# Get everything after first occurence of substring

Tags: bash, sed

There are lots of solutions for this working on a single character, but not for substrings. I have a close solution, but it deletes everything after the last occurrence of a substring:

```
$ echo pkg-new-pkg-20180925-090719.x86_64 | sed -n -e "s/^.*pkg-//p"
20180925-090719.x86_64
```

What I *want* is:

```
$ echo pkg-new-pkg-20180925-090719.x86_64 | ???
new-pkg-20180925-090719.x86_64
```

The substring I'm splitting on is `pkg-` in this case.
Any ideas?

Comment: You are mentioning "splitting" the string on a substring. Could you elaborate on this? Splitting `pkg-new-pkg-20180925-090719.x86_64` on the string `pkg-` would result in the three strings `""` (an empty string), `new-` and `20180925-090719.x86_64`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a variable:

```
var=pkg-new-pkg-20180925-090719.x86_64
printf '%s\n' "${var#*pkg-}"
```

`${var#pattern}` removes the shortest leading part that matches the pattern (`${var##pattern}` for the longest part).

On a text input stream:

```
sed 's/pkg-/\
/;s/.*\n//'
```

That replaces the *first* occurrence of `pkg-` with a newline character (a character which otherwise doesn't occur in the pattern space), and then removes everything up to that one newline character. Some `sed` implementations also allow you to write it `sed 's/pkg-/\n/;s/.*\n//'` though that's neither portable nor standard.

With ast-open `sed` (also works with `ssed -R`):

```
sed -E 's/.*?pkg-//'
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/.*?pkg-//'
```

Where `.*?` is the non-greedy version of `.*`.

Comment: Awesome that does the trick, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I have done by below mentioned 2 methods

First method

```
     echo "pkg-new-pkg-20180925-090719.x86_64"| sed "s/pkg-//"
new-pkg-20180925-090719.x86_64
```

Second method

```
echo "pkg-new-pkg-20180925-090719.x86_64"| awk -F "-" '{$1="";print $0}'| sed 's/^ //g'| sed "s/ /-/g"

new-pkg-20180925-090719.x86_64
```